# What happens if number of messages in mail inbox exceed int range?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have to read new e-mails constantly with JavaMail using POP3.

I'm going to implement such solution:

- count all mails (once, at the start of application)
- set `lastRead` to mails number
- periodically poll inbox and then:

  - count all mails and check if their number is greater than `lastRead`
  - if so, read new mails and update `lastRead`

It works fine at small sample, but I wonder what happens if the number of mails on the server exceed 2147483647.

I see that if I delete mail (from common client), it has no impact of number of mails returned by server to JavaMail or their numbers. But what if the mailbox will overflow? Will I have to stop and start application again?

The methods of Folder have `int`s as arguments (I think about `getMessages`, which I use). Is this ever possible for mailbox to have so many messages? Or maybe these ids are just reseting in some way? But this also won't be to good for my application.

Comment: Max `int` is much higher than 32767. It's 2^31-1.

Comment: @Eran Thanks. But the question remains unanswered ;)

Comment: There is `multithreading` for this

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız can you please write something more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously since JavaMail uses a Java int to represent the message number, it's not going to work if there are more than 2^31-1 messages.  It just seems extremely unlikely that that would happen for any real mailbox.  If you started receiving a new message every second, it would still be 68 years before you would reach that number.  If you have an application where this is a realistic possibility, you should manage the mailbox so that it never gets that large, e.g., by deleting messages, or moving them into archive mailboxes (which would require use of IMAP).

(Multithreading has nothing to do with this; I have no idea what Burak is thinking.)

Comment: OK, but let's say that i have 100 messages (for example), numbers from 1 to 100. What can I do with my mailbox to "reset" this mailbox? If I delete these messages, I assume that new message still will have the id of 101. So it doesn't apply my problem.
And if I can do anything to reset this id number, I have to stop my application at first, because I remember in application that 100 is last read message, so then the application won't process new messages.

Comment: You're confusing message (sequence) numbers with UIDs.  Message numbers are ints, UIDs are longs so UIDs can grow to 2^63-1.  You'll never run out.

Comment: But how can I use UIDs? Should I do it? Because now I'm only going to use messages ID.

Comment: Message-ID is yet something completely different; it's not what you want for your problem.  See the UIDFolder interface in JavaMail for UIDs, which works with IMAP but not POP3.  (There's almost no reason to use POP3 these days.)

Comment: The reason for using IMAP for me is bussiness requirement, I think I have no alternative for now. At the moment, messageID seems to work fine for me, is this something that could go wrong?

Comment: Great, you're using IMAP, so use UIDs.  The problem with the Message-ID header is that it's not guaranteed to be unique, and some messages might have no Message-ID header at all.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I have to use POP3... So I assume that I should rely rather on UIDs? But I can't, because they are not supportet with pop?

Comment: POP3 has its own kind of UIDs, but they're strings instead of numbers.  See the javadocs for the com.sun.mail.pop3 package for details.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. I hope the last question: where can I find proper documentation, when all the sources point to the java.net which is apparently closed? :(

Comment: The [JavaMail project has moved to GitHub](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  Hopefully redirects from the java.net web site will be in place soon.